# Implode and explode php mysql

Tags: php, explode, implode

HEY GUYS I implode a data from checkboxes this is the code:

```
To Show Checkboxes from Different tables:
  <?php
          $query23 = "SELECT * from tbl_occasions";
         $result23 = mysqli_query($conn, $query23)
            or die("Error in query: ". mysqli_error($conn));

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result23))
        {
         ?>
         <div class="col-md-12">
         <label class="checkbox" for="checkboxes"> 
                <input type="checkbox" name="reg_occassions[]"  value="<?php echo $row['name'];?>"><?php echo $row['name']?> 
         </label>
            </div>
         <?php
        }   
             ?>


  <?php
          $query24 = "SELECT * from tbl_categories";
         $result24 = mysqli_query($conn, $query24)
            or die("Error in query: ". mysqli_error($conn));

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result24))
        {
         ?>
         <div class="col-md-12">
         <label class="checkbox" for="checkboxes"> 
                <input type="checkbox" name="reg_categories[]"  value="<?php echo $row['name'];?>"><?php echo $row['name']?> 
         </label>
            </div>
         <?php
        }   
         ?>
```

To insert into database with implode:

```
 $occasions = implode( ';' , $_POST['reg_occassions'] );
 $categories= implode( ';' , $_POST['reg_categories'] );

 $query = "INSERT INTO tbl_flower (flower_type, website_description,florist_description,name,image,enabled,florist_choice,categories,occasions)
             VALUES ('$flowertype', '$websitedescription', '$floristdescription','$name', '$upfile', '$enabled','$floristchoice', '$categories','$occasions')";
```

This is working.  i made the result.... so the input need to be for example :

```
flower type       Occasions                            Categories

12 Red Roses      Birthday;Anniversary;Valentines      Bouqets
1 Red Rose        Birthday;Valentines               Bouqets;Flowerarrangment
```

Now i need to do a dropdownlist of occasions. If the user  choose Anniversary only 12 Red Roses will appear but if the user choose Birthday , both flowers need to appear.

I tried this code but it's not working right. He is showing me only flower that are with 1 type of occasions for example 24 Roses has Birthday occasion only and the user choose Birthday.

This is the code i tried:

```
  $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_occasions";
   $result= mysqli_query($conn, $query)
    or die("Error in query: ". mysqli_error($conn));
    $option ="";

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){  

         $option .= '<option  name = "'.$row['name'].'" value = "'.$row['name'].'">'.$row['name'].'</option>';

    }
```

And i show it in a dropdown list.

```
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $_SESSION['selected'] = $_POST['reg_occasion'];





            $query2 = "SELECT occasions from tbl_flower";

            $result2= mysqli_query($conn, $query2)
                or die("Error in query: ". mysqli_error($conn));

            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)){
                $data = $row["occasions"];
                $da = explode(";" , $data);




            }

    $query1= "SELECT * FROM tbl_flower WHERE occasions NOT LIKE '". $da ."'";

    $result1= mysqli_query($conn, $query1)
    or die("Error in query: ". mysqli_error($conn));

    $result1_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result1);




    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)){




    ?>

           <tr>

            <td><?php echo $row['name']?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['position']?></td>
            <td>  <a href="editoccasionposition.php?id= <?php
                echo $row['id']?>"><input type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" name="edit " value="Edit Position"></a></td>



         </tr>

         <?php
    }
   }

?>
```

If someone can help me i really appreciate, Thank you.

Comment: i would fix the db structure, it need to be normalized

Comment: you will help me ?

Comment: `NOT LIKE '". $da ."'` would be `NOT LIKE '%".$da."%'` because like clause use % around the string.

Comment: array to string conversion in

Comment: $query1= "SELECT * FROM tbl_flower WHERE occasions NOT LIKE '%". $da ."%'";